# Calendar to change class depending on date availability from SQL database

Tags: php, sql, date

I’m trying to create a laptop system where you can see if a laptop is booked out already, I have a MySQL table with the columns approved_start_date (as datetime) and approved_end_date (as datetime) and laptop_id (1,2,3,4). I have the booking system all working but would like to be able to show the availability of the laptops on the days. The calendar is literally just for display purposes to show availability not to actually do anything else. I just want to be able to change the class on the days so they are a different colour depending on how many laptops are already booked out.

I've tried searching but I'm very new to php and so am not really sure where to start with this at all to be honest so any help would be really appreciated!

This is the calendar that I was going to use -

```
    /* draws a calendar */
    function draw_calendar($month,$year,$events = array()){

    /* draw table */
    $calendar = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">';

    /* table headings */
    $headings = array('Su','Mo','Tu','We','Th','Fr','Sa');
    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row"><td class="calendar-day-head">'.implode('</td><td class="calendar-day-head">',$headings).'</td></tr>';

    /* days and weeks vars now ... */
    $running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_this_week = 1;
    $day_counter = 0;
    $dates_array = array();

    /* row for week one */
    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';

    /* print "blank" days until the first of the current week */
    for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):
     $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
     $days_in_this_week++;
    endfor;

    /* keep going with days.... */
    for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
     $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day">';
       /* add in the day number */
       $calendar.= '<div class="day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>';

       $calendar.= '</div></td>';
         if($running_day == 6):
           $calendar.= '</tr>';
           if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
             $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
           endif;
           $running_day = -1;
           $days_in_this_week = 0;
         endif;
         $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
       endfor;

       /* finish the rest of the days in the week */
       if($days_in_this_week < 8):
         for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++):
           $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"></td>';
         endfor;
       endif;

       /* final row */
       $calendar.= '</tr>';


       /* end the table */
       $calendar.= '</table>';

       /** DEBUG **/
       $calendar = str_replace('</td>','</td>'."\n",$calendar);
       $calendar = str_replace('</tr>','</tr>'."\n",$calendar);

       /* all done, return result */
       return $calendar;
     }

     function random_number() {
       srand(time());
       return (rand() % 7);
     }


    // Create date object to store the DateTime format
    $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $month);

    // Store the month name to variable
    $monthName = $dateObj->format('F');

    /* sample usages */
    echo '<h2>'. $monthName . ' ' . $year . '</h2>';


    // echo '<h2 style="float:left; padding-right:30px;">'.date('F',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year)).' '.$year.'</h2>';
    echo draw_calendar($month,$year,$events);
```

I basically want to show if all 4 laptops are booked out for the days to be a different colour, if all 3 a different colour and so on.

Any help would be really appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know exactly how you are getting the data back from your database but here is what you can try to do:

- Create 4 classes with different colors
- Have an array with the class names, ex:   `$colorClasses = ['','yellow','green','blue','purple'];` (I put one empty string in the beginning so  1 is at position 1 not 0)
- When you are creating the day check how many laptops are booked for tat day and use it for the index to add a class name dynamically based on the index in the array, ex: `$calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np ' . $colorClasses[$rentedOutCount].'"></td>';`  `$rentedOutCount` should be the number of laptops rented out for that day